# $rake db:migrate An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, sqlite, rake

I am new to RoR and I keep getting this error message:

```
$ rake db:migrate
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id"
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "email" varchar
(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've been searching for a solution for 3 days, but I cannot seem to find anything that works for me.

Thank you in advance for your help :)
PS - I am running off Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`table "users" already exists` seems to be the problem. Have you tried to manually remove the table from your database with some [SQLITE admin tool](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)?

Or you can include a remove table in your migration script (should be called create_users.rb inside your db/migrate folder). Inside `def up` insert `drop_table :users` :

```
      def up
         drop_table :users

         create_table :users do |t|
         t.string :name
         #...

         t.timestamps
      end
```

Oh and I remember from my RoR time that the table name "Users" can cause problems later on. Might be this is related.

Comment: thanks. I encounted this problem also. Solved by deleting my database

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if you are following Michael Hartl's tutorial on RoR.

But someone has said there's a problem in the steps of the tutorial http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=44944

`rake db:drop:all`    <---------- will **wipe everything** then run `rake db:migrate` again should fix the problem.

Good Luck

Comment: I had to run `rake db:create` after the `rake db:drop:all` before I could run `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the table already exists, you need to delete/remove it before executing the migration.

Easy, GUI way to do this is with the SQLite Database Browser (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).

Click the button with the Table-X icon. Choose User Table click Delete.

Then run `rake db:migrate`

Bada boom bada bing

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, then i did 
=> `rake db:drop`
=> `rake db:create`
=> `rake db:migrate`

worked perfectly.

But if it doesn't work we could try something like

`ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table('users')`

`ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table('users')`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after several hours I finally found the solution

I’ve put
def self.up

create_table :users do |t|

def down
    drop_down :users
  end
end

Then make rake db:migrate and Magic !!!!