# building Reddit replica using Rails, worried that early database construction is flawed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building my first Rails app (a replica of Reddit), and I've constructed two resources so far (Posts and Comments). Realizing that I need to have a way of organizing posts, I started to create a third resource, Topics. I started out on it by generating a model for topics and then running "rake db:migrate" to build a database for this model, but I soon realized that I left out one of the attributes for topics that I wanted to include when generating this model:

> rails generate model topic public:boolean description:text

I meant to also include name as an attribute ("name:string"). I didn’t know how to add this attribute in after I had already generated the model and built a database for it, and as I had just started to build this resource in a newly created git branch, I simply added and committed my work, switched back into the master branch, deleted the branch I had created, created a new branch and started over (shouldn't this have wiped the slate clean, making it as if I had never generated a Topic model and built a databse for it?) However, after beginning to build this resource again in a newly created branch (i.e. generating another model for topics and trying to build the database for this model) I was presented with a lengthy error message which began with

```
>Edwards-MacBook-Pro:bloccit Teddy$ rake db:migrate
>== 20160503195158 CreateTopics: migrating       >=====================================
>-- create_table(:topics)
>rake aborted!
>StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations    >canceled:

>SQLite3::SQLException: table "topics" already exists
```

This was confusing because I checked schema.rb and no topic table was present and, to my understanding, schema.rb represents an application's complete database architecture; the tables it uses and how those tables relate to each other... So if the topic table is not present in this file, it can't already exist, right?

Now, when I looked here on StackOverflow for a solution, I did find this question :[$rake db:migrate An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589874/rake-dbmigrate-an-error-has-occurred-this-and-all-later-migrations-canceled) , and the solution presented in it does seem to solve my issue. However, I'm a little uncertain that this is a solution for the problem I ran into because, as I stated, there was not yet a topic table in my database. If it is a solution, can someone please explain to me how I created this problem, why this solution solves my problem, and how it solves it?

I'm very much a newbie, and this is the first question I've ever asked here so I apologize in advance if this is not a good question. I read the guidelines on asking a good question in the help center, and I hope that I've followed them at least decently.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me to understand all of this.

Comment: Checkout my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37013713/6263819) to a similar question about adding fields after you've defined the initial schema.  All the basic steps are there.

Answer (score 0):

> I simply added and committed my work, switched back into the master branch, deleted the branch I had created, created a new branch and started over **(shouldn't this have wiped the slate clean, making it as if I had never generated a Topic model and built a databse for it?)**

No. The database is not version controlled by Git. Every branch shares the same database.

If you want to start from a blank slate, run `rake db:drop` to completely delete the database, and then `rake db:migrate` to recreate it from the ground up.

> ... and, to my understanding, schema.rb represents an application's complete database architecture;

Yes, it does, but it doesn't reflect the *actual database state* as it currently exists. It simply contains the entire structure needed to *create* the database. It is not tied to the real database, and it does not "live update" to reflect the real database. It only gets updated when you run `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:schema:dump`. You last migrated on a branch that you threw away, so the changes to schema.rb were thrown away as well.

> ... However, I'm a little uncertain that this is a solution for the problem I ran into because, as I stated, there was not yet a topic table in my database.

Yes, there *is* a `topics` table in your database. Don't rely on migrations or schema.db to show you what is in the database, neither of these things are actually *meant* to show you the current state of your database. Use `rails db` to start your database console (`psql` for example) and talk to the database *directly* to see what its current state is.